# Android TV App: How to show banner icon in Pre-lollipop Android TV Devices

Tags: android, icons, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I want to create an Android TV Application that should show bannerIcon in both pre-lollipop and post-lollipop Android TV Devices.

```
    <application
    android:name="com.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    android:banner="@drawable/ic_launcher_tv">


    </application>
```

Currently it showing Square Icon in Pre-Lollipop Android TV Device. But it is running fine in Android TV After 5.0 Version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android TV launched with Lollipop. You should not develop an Android TV app for pre-lollipop devices as they do not exist.

From the [Wikipedia on Lollipop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Lollipop): 
"Alongside Lollipop, the [I/O keynote] presentation focused on a number of new Android-oriented platforms and technologies, including Android TV"

In addition, looking at Android Studio, you cannot create an ATV emulator for pre-lollipop.

But for Amazon FireTV and FireTV Stick You can provide the promotional image during application's submission process, or alternatively update the metadata for an already submitted app. For that go into your app's detail's, switch to the 'Images & Multimedia' tab, click 'Edit' and next to 'Promotional image (Recommended) 1024 x 500px (landscape only) PNG or JPG' upload an image that can be used during promotions. After that it will show in place of Square ICON for more detail go through this [link](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/483/how-to-provide-the-firetv-and-firetv-stick-app-ban.html).

[image: Screen shot of Android Studio TV emulator options]

Comment: Benjamin, I agree with you we can't create android TV AVD for pre-lollipop devices but Amazon Fire TV Stick that support pre-lollipop android version, so how to show banner in that devices.

Comment: I am not familiar with Amazon Fire TV Stick but looking at the specs, they also run Lollipop (API 22) and above.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/device-and-platform-specifications

Comment: "Amazon Fire TV refers to the Fire TV set-top box or stick that run the Fire operating system (OS) on your TV. There are two versions of Fire OS: Fire OS 5 and 6. Fire OS 5 is a fork of Android 5.1 (Lollipop, API level 22), while Fire OS 6 is based on Android 7.1 (Nougat API, level 25)."

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/amazon-fire-tv-differences-from-android-tv-development

Comment: "SDK Level

Android TV often runs the latest version of Android (Nougat or API level 25). In contrast, Amazon Fire TV devices can run either Fire OS 5 (based on Lollipop, API level 22) or Fire OS 6 (based on Nougat, API level 25). Currently, the only device that runs Fire OS 6 is Fire TV (Gen 3). (Whether the previous Fire TV devices running Fire OS 5 will eventually be upleveled to Fire OS 6 or not is unknown/undecided.)"

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/amazon-fire-tv-differences-from-android-tv-development#sdk-level

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for this information but i found the solutions from this link https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/483/how-to-provide-the-firetv-and-firetv-stick-app-ban.html . We need this because Fire OS is based on android with some additional functionalities.